# Passing Data from XWalkView to Native Android

Tags: javascript, php, android, mysql, crosswalk

I have a question which may be simple for you guys. 
I'm running a WebApp using Crosswalk(XWalkView), everything looks smooth. I found out how to launch a native function from inside the website into my Android App.

```
public class WebAppInterface {
    @org.xwalk.core.JavascriptInterface
    public void callFunction() {
        onBuyGasButtonClicked(getCurrentFocus());

    }
```

I need to know how to pass data along with it. I'm using in-app-billing. I got their code samples and I think everything is going fine, but I need to update my PHP MySQL server with the amount purchased. 
How can I pass the variable to my Android App? (egs. email)

Answer (score 0):

Let's assuming passing a string from JavaScript to native code. Firstly, create a JavaScript interface as you did:

```
public class WebAppInterface {
    @org.xwalk.core.JavascriptInterface
    public void callFunction(String text) {
    }
}
```

Then, add the interface to your XWalkView object:

```
mXWalkView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(), "testObject");
```

In your JavaScript:

```
function test(text) { testObject.callFunction(text); }
```